# Feature tests that depend on tools that are being tested?

Tags: laravel, testing

I'm trying to improve my understanding of feature tests.

I randomly picked a Laravel project my friends did.  I see that they use the `app/` folder to organize all the usual things like models, data transfer objects, controllers, etc... basically all the application logic for the REST API this project is responsible for.

I also noticed a folder called `tests/feature` that contains what I recently learnt are feature tests.  What I found interesting was code that looked something like this:

```
use App\Profile;

class HobbyFeatureTest extends FeatureTestCase
{
    // other code ...etc...
    public function testGetUserHobbyyOnUserWithNoHobby()
    {
        $response = $this->getJson('api/user/me/hobbies')->assertOk();  /// makes a PHP curl call
        $response->assertJson($this->profile->hobby->toArray());
    }
    // other code ...etc...
}
```

Basically `$this->profile` is an instance of `App\Profile`.  And `api/user/me/hobbies` also depends on `App\Profile` in its construction.

I found this unusual because this means you're testing with the tools that are being tested?  Wouldn't doing feature tests with the same code base as the code to be tested problematic?

---

BACKGROUND TO MY QUESTION

It occurred to me that a few years ago, I wrote feature tests without knowing what they were really called.  What I did differently was I wrote all my feature tests in ruby language in a completely separate code base (git project) to test a restful API that was built in golang.   My ruby code would load mock database snapshots, then ping each golang api and evaluate their responses.  My motivation for having two code bases were:

1. I wanted the underlying code for my feature tests to be as exclusive as possible from the code being tested.  I was trying to implement the analog to [double-entry bookkeeping in accounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping).
2. I wanted my feature tests to be re-useable if I re-platform my API to a different technology.  This proved useful because the API was originally built with PHP5.  When PHP5 reached end-of-life, I rebuilt the API with golang under a new architecture (needed address some technical debt as well).  I was happy to be able to retain and re-use 90% of my ruby feature tests.

Based on my only other experience writing tests, it struck me as odd that Laravel took an approach that doesn't realize the benefits I mention in the two points above.  Hence, I want to understand better Laravel's motivation for implementing feature tests the way they did, or if there's something inherently wrong keeping your feature tests in a separate code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature tests in `Laravel`, is what i would call a modern integration test. Where as Integration tests, tests multiple parts of the system together. Hereby the database, the `Laravel` code, but not the web server as this is a fake approach to emulating an API and not using traditional approaches like `Apache` or `Nginx`.

The reasoning for this approach is very opinionated, but my take on it is. In traditional unit testing, you should mock most part of the system, that are not being tested. Models, Database layer etc. `Laravels` models are a hassle to mock, would take mocking every eloquent call, which can quickly become a couple. Instead in a Feature test, you can easily create a test that hits the whole system. This follows the underlying approach of Laravel, that it should be `with expressive, elegant syntax`, see [laravel.com](https://laravel.com/) for that quote.

```
public function testSeeProfile () {
    $profile = factory(Profile::class)->create();

    $response = $this->json('api/profile/' . $profile->id);

    $response->assertJson(...);
}
```

This is how easy you can write a test, that test logic, database layer and everything a developer cares about. In `Laravel` terminology, this is a feature test, which i would call a modern feature tests or really an integration test.

This does not replace real Feature tests, which should be done with `Dusk`, `Selenium`, `Cypress` or similar. Which i would keep in another separate project. It gets fuzzy when `Laravel` has Dusk, that can do that in your project. Thou it is not a "real" Feature test, before the real web server is being used and `Laravel` feature test still does not do that.

Comment: As testing methodology in literature is fairly vague on the differences between unit / integration and feature testing, this is fairly opinionated for an stackoverflow post, i hope i can enlighten you a bit on what i think is the design ideas behind what a Laravel feature test is.

Comment: This is great.  I have a quick follow up question. Is it common to have both real feature tests (eg. With dusk, selenium etc...) Along with laravel feature tests?  Or are the real feature tests generally sufficient?

Comment: What i have seen feature tests are more for flows in an application. Like registering to our application. Going through the front end making multiple api calls. Laravel feature tests are each endpoint with edge cases. So that one true feature tests, can be hit by 100's of small laravel feature tests. and the projects i been on where feature tests has been implemented, there are very few feature tests compared to the laravel ones. like 20 feature tests to 800 "unit tests". Where the cypress feature tests often run on regular schedules to tests if you break the app.